# How to get and use Docusign api key

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with several clients. And they want docusign integrated in their system. So I created developer account on the demo server and generated necessary credentials and completed all the necessary code to get docusign working for our clients. I am done with all api integrations at my end. 
Now clients have given me their docsuign account details and I dont know how to setup the different clients and how to get api key for them.

Answer (score 0):

Each application/integration for the DocuSign platform needs its own API key. In other words, the key is associated with the integration/app.

To generate a key, see item 2 (Generate Integrator Key) on the [Quick Start overview page.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/overview)

While you can use one demo/developer account and create multiple keys for it, I'd suggest that you create a different demo/developer account for each of your clients. You can create multiple [free developer/demo accounts](https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer) but each one needs a different email address. Having multiple accounts will let you customize each account to the particular needs of the related client.

In addition, it is good to test your integration against user names that access to more than one account. It is not uncommon for customers to have this type of access.

To do this, create two demo/developer accounts (two different emails). Then go to one of the accounts, use Preferences via the drop down menu by your name. Then go to Account Administration / Users on the left side. Then add the email from the other account to this account. (If you don't see the Administration section in the navigation then you need to switch to the Classic DocuSign Experience.)

Now when you log in, you can switch accounts (use the same menu under your name). You should then try your integration with the user name that has two accounts. Your integration should let you switch accounts in a way that is appropriate to the integration and its use case.

When one of your clients wants to test your integration with *their* **demo account**, just give them access to the integration--you would use the same integration key that you had been using. But the integration would now login with different username/pw credentials supplied by your client.

When one of your apps is ready for **production**, you first [certify](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification) it with DocuSign.

Once the app, and matching integration key, has been certified, you or your clients/customers can use the app with DocuSign's production platforms.